# addEventListener "click" - starts on page load

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, pageload

I can't understand, why addEventListener("click") starts after page loading, not waiting for "click". What is worse - it does not work on click again. Below you can find script:

```
const seven = document.getElementById("seven");
seven.addEventListener("click", typeNumber(7));
function typeNumber(a){
    calculations.innerText = calculations.innerText + a;
    
}
```

No matter what function I add to event listener (console log, alert etc) it always starts when the page starts. Are you able to help?

I tried to choose different types of function invocations

Comment: One thing, I think you need to do this: `seven.addEventListener("click", () => { typeNumber(7) })`.

Comment: that is because you are executing `typeNumber`, I assume you want `typeNumber` be the handler of the click event (e.g `seven.addEventListener("click", typeNumber);`). Keep in mind that your method gets the ClickEvent.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener It is because your handler should expect an event parameter, not a custom parameter. seven.addEventListener("click", typeNumber );

Comment: Quick-draw mcgraws over here, =P

Comment: gotta grind for that rep! @MarsAndBack haha

Comment: OP are you trying to add 7 to the current result (on each click)? At the moment all you'll be doing is adding a string to the existing string. You may need to [parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) the current result to a number first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `typeNumber` inside an anonymous function, rather than calling it immediately and passing the return value to `addEventListener` (when it expects a function as the second argument).

```js
const seven = document.getElementById("seven");
seven.addEventListener("click", () => typeNumber(7));
function typeNumber(a){
    document.getElementById("calculations").innerText = calculations.innerText + a;
}
```

```html
<button id="seven">7</button>
<p id="calculations"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are invoking the `typeNumber` function immediately when you add it as a callback to the event listener, rather than passing a reference to the function. This means that the function is executed immediately, rather than waiting for the event to occur.

you need to pass a reference to the function instead of invoking it:

```
const seven = document.getElementById("seven");
 seven.addEventListener("click", function() {
   typeNumber(7);
});


function typeNumber(a){
    calculations.innerText = calculations.innerText + a;
}
```

the `typeNumber` function will only be executed when the `click` event occurs on the `seven` element.